# Site em C# e MVC muito lento

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Desenvolvi um site em MVC e C#, porem após implantar no servidor Gogaddy tenho notado que o primeiro acesso é muito, mas muuuuuito lento mesmo.

Praticamente eu verifico se existe um usuário logado, caso não tenha eu redireciono para a tela de login para que seja feita o acesso.

A parte da verificação quanto o *login*, demora muito para ser realizada, porem após feito tudo isso, o site funciona normal, como se tudo estivesse normal.

Existe alguma ferramenta onde é possível ver o que e onde está o gargalo do meu site?

Comment: Essa demora acontece no começo do acesso de CADA seção, ou no primeiro acesso da primeira seção? Ou seja, se você for acessar de outra máquina, vai ocorrer essa demora?

Answer (score 2):

Este comportamento é normal na primeira publicação. Ocorre por dois motivos:

- As *Views* são recompiladas na primeira requisição;
- As *Migrations* são executadas se a primeira requisição faz algum acesso a dados.

Agora, se a lentidão continua durante as requisições, pode ser que exista um gargalo de banco de dados na sua aplicação. Vale a pena para esses casos realizar um *Debug* das *Actions* que demoram mais para executar.

Answer (score 2):

Isto é relativamente comum. O próprio ASP.NET MVC possui muitos componentes que precisam de *warm-up* para começar trabalhar em ordem.

Claro que pode ser que o seu caso seja um ponto fora da curva, mas acredito que não.

Se quiser verificar o que está atrasando a execução você precisa fazer o perfilamento da aplicação. Algumas ferramentas disponíveis específicas para esta tecnologia:

- [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)
- [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)
- [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) (não específico)
- [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) (não específico e pago)

O fenômeno indicado na outra resposta não acontece mais nas versões mais recentes, pelo menos não de forma sensível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 por essas ferramentas de profiling que eu n conhecia

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o Application Pool do seu site está hibernando após um tempo de inatividade, comum de acontecer com sites que ainda não tem muitos acessos.

Como ele hiberna, ele demora um tempo para reiniciar.

Se isso o incomoda muito, você pode :

1 - Verificar se é possível zerar o "Idle Timeout" no IIS. (Creio que não)

2 - Se não for possível fazer essa configuração, então para evitar que o site hiberne, você pode usar um serviço de monitoramento ou de ping que irá "pingar" a url do seu site a cada minuto, e assim o site não irá hibernar mais.
Você também pode fazer um programinha que chama a url do seu site a cada 10 minutos.

Mas assim que seu site for mais utilizado, esse "problema" será menos perceptível.

Referências :
https://www.godaddy.com/help/customize-iis-settings-3971

http://hostingperformance.guru/2014/03/iis-application-pool/