# Melhorar performance de código em C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, engenharia-de-software, otimização

Estou fazendo alguns teste com alguns códigos em C# e durante uma análise percebi que alguns problemas de altos picos acontecem quando ocorre conversões de valores inteiros para *string*, na grande maioria a conversão acontece assim: `classe.valor.ToString("0.0")` existe alguma forma de melhorar esse tipo de conversão? Utilizando `string.Format("{0:0.00}", classe.valor)` o pico ficou ainda mais alto reduzindo o desempenho da aplicação. Teria alguma alternativa?

Essas conversões acontecem dentro de uma função continua, que é atualizada a cada *frame*.

Não da para postar o código inteiro aqui os valores provem de diversas classes então irei postar só alguns trechos de uma das classes, assim posso aplicar nas outras:

```
distancia.text = string.Concat(string.Format("{0:0.00}", distance.metros), " m");

 if (contar)
    {
        i -= Time.deltaTime;

        timeCount.text = i.ToString("0").Replace("0","Go");

        if (i < 0)
        {                
            contar = false;
        }
    }

checkpoint.text = string.Concat("Distance: ", string.Format("{0:0.00}", distance.metros), " m");

if (manager.count)
    {
      var valor = int.Parse(rota.metros.ToString("00"));
      _menuManager.ShowMenu(Menu);
      endPoints.text = string.Concat("distance: ", string.Format("{0:0.00}", rotaMaior.metros), " m");
    }
```

Comment: Olhando só isto fica difícil indicar alguma coisa. Poste o resto do código, onde exatamente há o pico, como você mediu, enfim, dê mais detalhes para podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só olhando este trecho não tem nada que possa ser feito para obter resultados significativamente melhores. Eu poderia dizer para você fazer uma função de formatação própria, mas provavelmente ela seria menos eficiente. Eu poderia dizer para tirar isto que está causando o problema, mas você precisa dele, não deve ter usado à toa.

Tem um `_menuManager.ShowMenu(Menu)` esquisito aí. Parece estar misturando UI com processamento de dados, isto não deveria ocorrer, é engenharia de software ruim. Eu daria um jeito de separar melhor as coisas, e pode ser que este método é que esteja causando o problema. Ele me parece absurdamente mais pesado que o resto da operação.

Tem que tentar isolar o problema de alguma forma, ver exatamente onde está o problema, não dá para chutar. Ou faz uma medição no local ou usa uma ferramenta de *profiling* como as que eu indiquei [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76956/101).

O método `Concat()` é bastante eficiente. E mesmo que não fosse, ele não teria problemas nestes caso já que a concatenação tem poucos itens.

Este código pode estar sendo chamado mais vezes do que o necessário.

Fora isto, só mesmo se tiver outras partes que possam estar causando isto, talvez isto esteja em um laço mal montado.

Comment: sim, trata-se de um elemento UI, com alguns outros componentes como por exemplo animações de transações, é realmente muita coisa para postar aqui, mais para se ter uma noção de "tal" otimização que estou fazendo, apenas mudando a forma de concatenação de string Ex: `TextBox.text = variavelString1 + variavelString2` para `TextBox.text = string.Concat(variavelString1, variavelString2)` já esta reduzindo altos impactos, então imaginei que soluções curtas ou simples dicas serviriam =), e eu utilizo o profiling.

Comment: Acho estranho porque o compilador faz justamente o que você está dizendo que fez manualmente, então não é para ter diferença alguma. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10341188/221800

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Se você usa o *profiling* deve saber onde exatamente está o maisor gargalo, seria bom colocar os resultados do *profiling* na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Há muitas coisas que podem ser feitas para deixar a performance do seu código muito melhor.

Porém, há duas coisas que você realmente deve fazer e refatorar afim de elevar a performance rapidamente:

1. Separar saídas de processamento: No seu código está muito misturado o processamento dos seus cálculos com *output* para sua interface. Recomendo remover tudo e transformar todo isso em uma objeto de verdade, fechado para modificação mas aberto para extensão. Aparentemente você está usando um tipo de *Timer*, ele deve ter evento como * TimeElapsed* ou algo assim. Use-o para atualizar sua interface, assim esse processamento ficará em uma *thread* separada, isolando o fluxo principal
2. Melhore os *casting* - conversão de tipos - e manipulação de *string* do seu código. Essas conversões são custosas, principalmente se executadas em *loop*. E manipular *strings* também é custoso, por elas serem imutáveis.

Alguns exemplos:

```
//distancia.text = string.Concat(string.Format("{0:0.00}", distance.metros), "m");
distancia.text = string.Format("{0:0.00} m", distance.metros); // Removido um Concat()

//checkpoint.text = string.Concat("Distance: ", string.Format("{0:0.00}", distance.metros), " m");
checkpoint.text = string.Format("Distance: {0:0.00} m", distance.metros); // Removido um Concat()

//endPoints.text = string.Concat("distance: ", string.Format("{0:0.00}", rotaMaior.metros), " m");
endPoints.text = string.Format("distance: {0:0.00} m", rotaMaior.metros); // Removido um Contac()
```

Usar operadores ternários:

```
//timeCount.text = i.ToString("0").Replace("0","Go");
timeCount.text = i > 0 ? i : "Go"; // Removido ToString() e Replace()
```

Redução de *casting*:

```
//var valor = int.Parse(rota.metros.ToString("00")); // Qual o tipo desse rota.metros ?
var valor = rota.metros; //Não vi onde você usar esse 'valor'
```

E concordo com o @Maniero, esse `_menuManager.ShowMenu(Menu)` está estranho neste lugar. Se puder compartilhar mais código, irá nos ajudar a te ajudar mais.